# How to design the web page for minimum format loss when pasting into MS Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I am developing a web application and I want the users to be able to copy some parts of the page and paste them into MS Word *with minimum loss of html formatting*. For example users should be able to copy only a table from the page and paste it into word with minimum loss (assume that the page contains necessary mean,scripts to select only a single table or div).

How should I develop the html so that users can copy-paste with minimum loss? For example should I prefer tags like b,i instead of css, should I prefer inline css etc.

Comment: In my experience it all comes down to clean, semantic code, and what version of Office you are using. Is the page only for a controlled environment aka inter-office intranet or for the whole world to see?

Comment: The application will be available for the whole world. It is not a controlled environment but we can ignore versions older than 2007 and focus on Office 2010 and 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't rely on external CSS you're good; either inline CSS or tags such as B will do the trick.
Should probobly stick to CSS2 - no CSS3 fanciness. Only use websafe fonts of course, they have to be avaliable on the client's machine. If users will be able to copy multiple container elements you might want to design using tables  rather than divs. Stick to a strict layout and don't use absolutely positioned elements and stuff like that. Aim for a strict, square and narrow layout that will fit an a4 page nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what your users will paste, the save option is to make that part in a seperate page so that it is easy to paste.

By default MS-Word will give the same formatting but the width is always fixed, which can cause some issues (too wide or too narrow).

Another point to consider is that copying from a website always follows the flow of the HTML and not how it may appear in the browser. So all the to be pasted data need to be adjacent in HTML.

Be careful about:

- absolute positioned elements, overlays, etc.
- Elements that are scripted or dynamically loaded using Ajax

Scripts will always be dropped

To test it just paste something into word and than save the word-file in HTML.
See how it looks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you aware of any problems about dynamically created or modified elements using javascript( especially jquery in this case)? Some elements are created or modified before copying but as far as I know the actual html at the time of copy should be copied as is.

Comment: All HTML that is dynamically created will also be copied if it is within the flow of the document and not absolute positioned.